# How to cache auth()->user() with relationship like role in Laravel cache to reduce calls to DB?

Tags: laravel, caching, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I am building an application that is using [lighthouse-php](https://lighthouse-php.com/). Because I have constantly set various policies for different users, I constantly query for user model with a role relationship in different parts applications, and for this reason, would want to store the users in the Redis database and query from there instead.
I read couple of articles that I found on the internet such as: [laravel-cache-authuser](https://paulund.co.uk/laravel-cache-authuser); [creating-a-caching-user-provider-for-laravel/](https://matthewdaly.co.uk/blog/2018/01/12/creating-a-caching-user-provider-for-laravel/); [caching-the-laravel-user-provider-with-a-decorator/](https://matthewdaly.co.uk/blog/2020/03/11/caching-the-laravel-user-provider-with-a-decorator/), reviewed code in here [laravel-auth-user](https://github.com/wenzhan510/laravel-auth-user), and kind of understood the concept but struggling to understand laravel deep enough to find a suitable solution...

For example, I am struggling to understand how to store `User` with `Role` relationship inside event method in UserObserver, it's clear how to do it with one Model but not with a relationship attached.

I had a sense that I should do something like that:

```php
class UserObserver
{
    /**
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function saved(User $user)
    {
        $user->load('role');
        Cache::put("user.$user->id", $user, 60);
    }
}
```

But this way I make 2 calls to the DB, rather than having the relationship pre-loaded. How could I preload the relationship in the events arguments. I tried to add `protected $with = ['role']` so that child model/relationship always loaded. But no matter what I make more calls to DB either to retrieve Role or to retrieve User and Role.

He is some simplified code samples from my project [lighthouse-php](https://lighthouse-php.com/).

schema.graphql:

```
type SomeType {
    someMethod(args: [String!]): [Model!] @method @can(ability: "isAdmin",  model: "App\\Models\\User")
}

type User {
    id: ID
    name: String
    role: Role @belongsTo
}

type Role {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    label: String!
    users: [User!] @hasMany
}
```

User Model with role relationship:

```php
class User extends Authenticatabl {
    public function role(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }
}
```

User Policy that is used on some of the graphql type fields:

```php
class UserPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function isAdmin(): Response
    {
        $user = auth()->user();

        return $user->role->name === 'admin'
            ? $this->allow()
            : $this->deny('permission denied');
    }

    public function isManager(): Response
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $this->allow();

        return $user->role->name === 'manager' || $user->role->name === 'admin'
            ? $this->allow()
            : $this->deny('Permission Denied');
    }

}
```

Lighouse custom Query Class for resolving fields via methods.

```
class SomeType {
    public function someMethod(): string
    {
       // this triggers db call rather than receiving `role->name` from redis along with user
       return auth()->user()->role->name;
    }
}
```

If I make graphql query that looks something like this (please see below) it causes role relationship to be loaded from db, instead of cache.

```
query {
   user {
     id
     name
     role {
       id
       name
     }
   }
}
Please help.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could cache the relationship by creating a custom `accessor` for the `role` attribute on the `User` model. An example could be :

```
<?php 

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache; 

class User extends Authenticatabl {

    public function role(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }

    public static function getRoleCacheKey(User $user): string
    {
        return sprintf('user-%d-role', $user->id);
    }

    // Define accessor for caching purposes
    public function getRoleAttribute(): Collection
    {
        if ($this->relationLoaded('role')) {
            return $this->getRelationValue('role');
        }
        
        // Replace 3600 for the amount of seconds you would like to cache
        $role = Cache::remember(User::getRoleCacheKey($this), 3600, function () {
            return $this->getRelationValue('role');
        });

        $this->setRelation('role', $role);

        return $role;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `rememberForever()` function to cache it forever. Be aware that you would have to write an implementation to either remove / update the caching manually, as it will hold the value forever. You could create a function that clears the caching like so:

```
// In User model
public static function forgetRoleCaching(User $user): bool
{
    return Cache::forget(sprintf(User::getRoleCacheKey($user));
}
```

Your code in the observer can be updated to the following:

```
class UserObserver
{
    /**
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function saved(User $user)
    {
        // in case user role is cached forever
        User::forgetRoleCaching($user);

        $user->load('role'); // will trigger the accessor an should cache again
        Cache::put("user.$user->id", $user, 60);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can store your auth user with your relation using Session.

example :

```
$auth = Auth::User();
Session::put('user',$auth);

Session::put('relation',$auth->relation);
```

May it help you

Comment: Yes but, I am trying to store the whole object in the model with relationship

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named "user.php" under "App\Config" path. File should look like this

```
<?php

return [
    'role' => ''
];
```

Now you can set a config

```
config(['user.role' => $example_role]);
```

Then you can read from any file whenever you need this data

```
config('user.role');
```

This is my solution and i set this config value in middleware, works flawless.